# arfimaroll and external regressor

Tags: r, finance, quantitative-finance

im trying to forecast the volatility of some stocks with different models (e.g AR, HAR etc.). Now im at a point where I dont know how to proceed. My Problem is the following. I am trying to forecast the volatility with an ARFIMA (2,d,0) model and a external regressor. I am using the package rugarch and the command arfimaroll. 
Here is the Code for the ARFIMA specification.

```
specGT<- arfimaspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2, 0),arfima=T, external.regressors = TGT))
```

TGT is the external regressor. It is a matrix with 1 column and 1359 rows (the same number of rows as my data set). This code works (at least its not giving any errors).
Now I want to use arfimaroll to predict the volatility. Here is the code

```
forecastarfimaGT<-arfimaroll(specGT,lagRV_d,n.ahead=1,n.start=1014,refit.every=1,refit.window="recursive",solver="hybrid")
```

This also gives no errors. But if i compare the forecasts from the model with the external regressor with the ones from the same ARFIMA model without an external regressor it gives me the same values

```
forecastarfimaGT==forecastarfimarealized
```

Output is TRUE at every of the 345 forecast points.

Some notes on the forecast. refit.window="recursive" is used to perform a extending window forecast, the other arguments shouldnt matter (like refit.every and so on).

Now my question is what i am doing wrong here. Can someone give me a hint on my error?

Greetings

EDIT:
To make it more clear here is an fictive example. First lets make a timeseries with the data

```
a<-abs(rnorm(600,0.1,0.1)
```

Then make a vector of the external regressor and transform it into a matrix

```
b<-abs(rnorm(600,1,1))
b1<-as.matrix(b,nrow=600,ncol=1)
```

Now the arfima forecast without the external regressor

```
spec<- arfimaspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2, 0),arfima=T))
forecastarfima<-arfimaroll(spec,a,n.ahead=1,n.start=500,refit.every=1,refit.window="recursive",solver="hybrid"
forecastarfimadf<-as.data.frame(forecastarfima)
forecastarfimarealized<-forecastarfimadf[,-c(1:5)]
```

The forecast with the exernal regressor

```
specGT<- arfimaspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2, 0),arfima=T, external.regressors = b1))
forecastarfimaGT<-arfimaroll(specGT,a,n.ahead=1,n.start=500,refit.every=1,refit.window="recursive",solver="hybrid"
forecastarfimaGTdf<-as.data.frame(forecastarfimaGT)
forecastarfimarealizedGT<-forecastarfimaGTdf[,-c(1:5)]
```

Now lets compare the two results

```
forecastarfimarealized==forecastarfimarealizedGT
  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[37] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[73] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

As you can see booth vectors are identical. This shouldnt be the case. Even if the external regressor has no influence, the vectors shouldnt be the exact same. Im very confused right now. Am i using the right method? Can you help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are looking to the original series:

```
cbind(forecastarfimarealized,forecastarfimarealizedGT,a[501:600])
```

Look at "`Mu`". Try instead:

```
cbind(forecastarfimadf[,c(6,1)],forecastarfimaGTdf[,1])
plot.ts(cbind(forecastarfimadf[,c(6,1)],forecastarfimaGTdf[,1]),plot.type="single",col=2:4,ylab="x")
legend("top",c("realized","forecast x","forecast x+GT"),lty=1,col=2:4,bty ="n")
```

Are you sure you are modelling volatility? Maybe you must look at "`Sigma`" for that. Why not use Garch and the family?